# Merge of large tables fills transaction log

Tags: sql-server-2012

Merge of large tables fills transaction log.
Our ETL uses MERGE to import data from hospital information system.  When number of records exceeds several million the transaction log fills.  How can I restructure the statement so that the impact on transaction log is minimized?  Top()?  Openrowset?

Our query is built dynamically in SSIS using variables.  Here is what it looks like:
--Man query concatenates Mergequery1 to 5.  All are shown below.
--Main query

```
begin transaction;

begin try



declare @MergeQuery varchar(max)

set @MergeQuery = convert(varchar(max), @MergeQuery1) +  convert(varchar(max), @MergeQuery2)
+ ' ' + convert(varchar(max), @MergeQuery3)
+ ' ' + convert(varchar(max), @MergeQuery4)
+ ' ' + convert(varchar(max), @MergeQuery5);


exec(@MergeQuery);

end try

begin catch

 declare
  @Message VARCHAR(4000)
  ,@Severity INT
  ,@State  INT;

 select
  @Message = ERROR_MESSAGE()
  ,@Severity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
  ,@State = ERROR_STATE();

 if @@TRANCOUNT > 0
  rollback transaction;

 raiserror(@Message, @Severity, @State);

end catch;

if @@trancount > 0
begin

 commit transaction;


end



--Mergequery1  section modified
"begin transaction

 begin try
  begin

   declare @ChangeSum table(change varchar(25));
   declare @Inserted int = 0;
   declare @Updated int = 0;

   merge top (1000000) into "+ @[User::VISNDestinationDatabase] +"." + @[User::DataDestinationTable]   +  " prod
   using " + @[User::VISNStagingDestinationTable]  + " stag
   on " + @[User::MergeOnResult] +

  "  when MATCHED then
   update set " +@[User::MergeUpdTextResult]   

--Mergequery2
@[User::MergeUpdTextResult2]  + " when not matched by target then"

--Mergequery3
"   insert
     ( " + @[User::MergeInsertResult] + 
  "       
     )"`enter code here`

--Mergequery4
  "values
     ( "
      + @[User::MergeValueResult]+
  "   )"

--Mergequery5
"output $action into @ChangeSum;

   set @Inserted = (select count(*) from @ChangeSum where change = 'INSERT');
   set @Updated = (select count(*) from @ChangeSum where change = 'UPDATE');

 select @Inserted as Inserted, @Updated as Updated;

  end
 end try

 begin catch
  rollback
 end catch

if @@trancount > 0
commit transaction"
```

Comment: Use Simple recovery model and batch your inserts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602872/tsql-insert-transaction-log-filling-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that most of the transaction log is generated by the UPDATE part of the MERGE (are you really inserting millions of new rows or is it mostly updates?), there may be an easy way to fix this.

In the WHEN MATCHED part add an AND condition to make sure the columns being updated have actually changed in the source. For example:

```
...
WHEN MATCHED AND (stag.ColumnA <> prod.ColumnA OR stag.ColumnB <> prod.ColumnB)
THEN UPDATE SET prod.ColumnA = stag.ColumnA, prod.ColumnB = stag.ColumnB 
...
```

In general though, you need to find a way to break the staging table in batches. In this scenario, the best way to do this would be by the clustering key on the staging table. For example assuming the staging table is clustered by an integer ID column, you would select e.g. TOP 100000 rows from it ordering by ID then merge this batch into prod, while noting the last ID that was read. The next batch would start at MaxID + 1, etc. To determine the last read ID, add a new ID column to your @ChangeSum table variable, then modify the OUTPUT clause as follows:

```
output stage.ID, $action into @ChangeSum;
```

then to get the MaxID:

```
SELECT @MaxID = MAX(ID) FROM @ChangeSum;
```

Comment: Thank  you.  I have added a clustered index to source (Stage) and yes the problem was caused by inserts on initial load.  I left the merge alone and introduced branching logic in my SSIS package that lets a dataflow do the heavy lifting with a fast load with minimal logging.

I wish I knew how to mimic what SSIS does with an insert but among other things I'm told issuing a tablock is important as is the clustered index on source.